# My java compiles fine but displays nothing

Tags: java, arrays

Hello I'm trying to make a program that check first letter of a word and see if it equals the last letter.

```
public class isPalindrome
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // Create an array of strings to test.
      String[] testStrings = { "Able was I ere I saw Elba",
                                "Rats live on no evil star",
                               "Four score and seven years ago",
                               "Barrack Obama",
                               "Now is the time for all good men",
                               "Desserts I stressed",
                               "Ask not what your country can do for you",
                               "Kayak",
                               "Vegeta",
                               "A Man, A Plan, a canal, Panama!"};

      for (int i = 0; i < testStrings.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.print("\"" + testStrings[i] + "\"");
         if (Palindrome(stripString(testStrings[i])))
            System.out.println(" is a palindrome.");
         else
            System.out.println(" is not a palindrome.");
      }
   }


   public static String stripString(String strip)
   {
        strip = strip.toUpperCase();
        String stripped= "";
        for (int i= 0; i< strip.length(); i++) 
        {
            if (Character.isLetter(strip.charAt(i)))

                stripped += strip.charAt(i);
        }
        return stripped;
   }


   public static boolean Palindrome(String str)
   {
      boolean status = false;

      if (str.length() <= 1)
         status = true;
      else if (str.charAt(0) == str.charAt(str.length()-1))//Recursive Case
      {    
        status = Palindrome (str.substring (1, str.length()-1));
      }
      return status;
   }
}
```

Comment: Really nothing at all? At least stuff from the for loop should print...

Comment: This looks fine to me, is the program terminating? Or does it get stuck on an infinite loop somewhere?

Comment: The program isn't terminating it's compiling normally, there something I'm missing?.

Comment: By terminating I mean: Does the program execution finish and even still nothing is printed out?

Comment: I just tested this. It works. How do you execute it?

Comment: The program executes and then completes. However nothing displays

Comment: @user: again: **how** do you execute it?

Comment: +1 for "Rats live on no evil star", that made my day :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My java compiles fine but displays nothing.

Yes it does:

```
#~/temp$ javac isPalindrome.java
#~/temp$ java isPalindrome 
"Able was I ere I saw Elba" is a palindrome.
"Rats live on no evil star" is a palindrome.
"Four score and seven years ago" is not a palindrome.
"Barrack Obama" is not a palindrome.
"Now is the time for all good men" is not a palindrome.
"Desserts I stressed" is a palindrome.
"Ask not what your country can do for you" is not a palindrome.
"Kayak" is a palindrome.
"Vegeta" is not a palindrome.
"A Man, A Plan, a canal, Panama!" is a palindrome.
```

Could it be that you're not running it after compiling it? This command compiles it:

```
javac isPalindrome.java
```

and then this one runs it:

```
java isPalindrome
```

**Edit**: Or you may need:

```
java -cp . isPalindrome
```

...to tell Java to look for classes in the current directory. (I don't in my largely un-customized Java install, but you used to have to, so...)

---

**Off-topic**: This is **nothing** to do with the problem, but: In Java, the coding convention (which you're free to ignore) is that class names start with a capital letter, and method names start with a lower-case letter. So the class would be `IsPalindrome` (or `PalindromeTester` or something), and then the method `Palindrome` would be `isPalindrome` or similar. If you use the convention, it'll be easier to work with other people, because you won't confuse them with unusual naming of things. :-)

Comment: I don't understand how you got this??

Comment: @user: I've added a note at the end -- could it be that having compiled it, you're not *running* it?

Comment: #~/temp$ javac isPalindrome.java do i add a ; or } to the end of it??.

Comment: @user: See the commands I listed for how to compile and run. What you actually type is `javac isPalindrome.java` and then you press Enter (this is at the command line; the `~/temp$` is just my command prompt on my Linux box, like `c:\temp>` on Windows; you don't type that bit). To run it, you type `java isPalindrome` and press Enter.

Comment: Okay thanks crowder. When i run this on my computer i get exception in main thread?.

Comment: @user: I just added an alternate for the command to run it, you may need `java -cp . isPalindrome` to tell Java to look for classes in the current directory (`-cp` for classpath, `.` for "current directory").

Comment: Thank you very much for who ever corrected my post. My program compiles